# Clear search box after button clicked

Tags: javascript, function, event-listener

I am trying to clean search box after clicked on button, it is google maps search and for now I can clear serach results from map but not search box.

```
<div class="search-box">
            <input id="searchBox" type="text"  placeholder="Search your location">
            <div class="search-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="cancel-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="search-data"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="wipe" type="submit" class="mybtn" onClick="wipeOut()">Clear</button>
        </div>
```

and js code

```
   function clearSearch() { 
    document.getElementById("wipe").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('searchBox').value = "";
}
)}



   function wipeOut() {
  let clearAll = document.getElementsByName("searchType");
  for(let i = 0; i < clearAll.length; i++) {
    clearAll[i].checked = false;
  }
  clearSearch();
  clearResults();
  clearMarkers(); 
}
```

wipeOut function is for clearing radio buttons, clearMarkers and clearResults are for google map markers and results.

I was looking for the simplest way to clear search box, and it is kinda working but only after I clicked Clear button twice, the markers and results are cleared with one click.
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In clearSearch you have an additional event handlers for the same button that you already have the inline click handler. Which means in order to trigger the clearSearch click you have to click twice. Just combine the two and get rid of the inline onclick. I also commented out the two functions that weren't included so you will want to remove the commenting for them.

```js
document.getElementById("wipe").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('searchBox').value = "";
  
  let clearAll = document.getElementsByName("searchType");
  for(let i = 0; i < clearAll.length; i++) {
    clearAll[i].checked = false;
  }
  
  //clearResults();
  //clearMarkers(); 
});
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <input id="searchBox" type="text" placeholder="Search your location">
  <div class="search-icon">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="cancel-icon">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="search-data"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="wipe" type="submit" class="mybtn">Clear</button>
</div>
```